# Own copy of mono.data.sqlite.dll

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.android

So I have rebuilt the `mono.data.sqlite.dll` with some extra compiler directives. I put a reference to that new dll. All works well in debug, emulators and actual devices use my new `mono.data.sqlite.dll`.

As soon as I build the apk file it loses my one and goes back to the one shipped with Xamarin.Android. What do I need to do for it to use my one? Can I even do it this way?

Comment: Android doesn't use DLLs, so I'm not sure what you think you're accomplishing, but its unlikely to work.  DLLs are a Windows only file format.  Android is Linux based, it uses .so files.

Comment: @GabeSechan notice the Xamarin tag. Xamarin uses dlls and can have native libraries bundled inside of them if needed.

Comment: @Cheesebaron A dll is a linked library, which is basically executable code with a few headers.  Unless there's a totally new format for them that uses the same name, there's no way to embed a .so file inside of one.

Comment: @GabeSechan not sure what you call embedded resources in dll's then... You can embed anything as resource in a dll. In Xamarin.Android binding libraries, you embed jars, aars and even so files in a dll and have wrappers calling into that. Enlighten yourself by reading: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/ This discussion, however, does not help OP. I'd be happy to take it elsewhere.

Comment: @Cheesebaron SO in other words, yes they did completely rewrite it, because the original version was a PE file.

Comment: @GabeSechan not sure how long it has been there. Probably since .NET3.5 or maybe even earlier. Anyways, the mono VM running alongside Dalvik and ART in Xamarin.Android apps consumes these dll's just fine :)

Comment: @Farrow how do you verify that the dll being referenced in your app is incorrect? From what I can see on nuget there has been a couple of other nugets that rebuild mono.data.sqlite, which could have been working. I can't see why anything would replace your assembly unless you tell it to. Can you maybe share some more details on what you are doing? What does your reference look like?

Comment: @Cheesebaron (your in Alabama right ?! - we have met)  Basically I know its referencing the wrong one because the compiler directives remove an error from the mono.data.sqlite.dll  when its running and once its packaged in the apk I still get the error, otherwise running the from the ide I do not.

Comment: @Farrow nope. Never been to Alabama, not US based. Do you build `mono.data.sqlite` when you also build your App? You say that it works well in debug on emulators and devices. But when you then switch to release mode it stops working? If you are building `mono.data.sqlite` in the same solution, please make sure the compiler directives are the same for that library in both `DEBUG` configuration and `RELEASE`.

Comment: Oh have you ever been to the USA ?!  Its when I archive the apk.  Its like my version of the sqlite dll doesnt make it to the apk.  Can I verify that somehow - the apk is just a zip file right?